# How can I obtain "pixel-perfect" connected components in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to obtain pixel-perfect connected components in an image using OpenCV. For example, in this image there are three connected components, the two rectangles and the background:

[image]

However, OpenCV's `connectedComponents()` function thinks there are only two, considering the rectangles to be a single component, I guess because they're so close (2 pixels) together:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

filepath = "test.png"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)

    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    value_channel = hsv_image[:, :, -1]

    n_components, component_map = cv2.connectedComponents(
        binarized_values,
        connectivity=4
    )
    print(n_components) # prints 2
```

Is there a way to get truly pixel-perfect connected components?

Note that I need an answer for Python, and PyOpenCV does not seem to support the `ccltype` parameter [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5) to set the algorithm.

Comment: I don’t see three connected components here. The rectangle seems a unique white blob. Unless the compression is affecting your image, OpenCV seems to be right.

Comment: @stateMachine White? Is the image not loading in your browser or something? It's a picture of two *black* rectangles on a white background.

Comment: I see there’s a white border in your image - is that the second rectangle you mention? Even so, the border shares 4 and 8 adjacency with the “central” rectangle, so both rectangles are labeled as one component.

Comment: Component analysis is carried out on white blobs, if you want to process the black regions as blobs you need to invert the image before the analysis.

Comment: @stateMachine Thank you! That was it. Jeeze, they might have mentioned that in the docs. I was half-way to implementing my own connected component algorithm.

Comment: You can also use findContours function

Comment: @JackM File a bug on OpenCV's github, suggesting improvement to the documentation. Seems like it could definitely use some overhaul in this case. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python Wand, which uses ImageMagick. Here is the ImageMagick command line for that. It finds 3 regions: two black rectangles and the white strip connected to the outer white border.

```
convert J3UDP.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 null:

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  1: 80x96+4+6 43.5,53.5 7680 gray(0)
  2: 80x96+86+6 125.5,53.5 7680 gray(0)
  0: 170x109+0+0 84.5,56.4 3170 gray(255)
```